# Simulate a lot of different IP's hitting a website

Tags: webserver, ip-spoofing, geolocation

This may sound like launching a DDOS, but I am testing out GEO-IP location on my applications. I need to gather some data, to check how my graphs look when there is a lot of data.
Are there any tools available where I can paste in an URL and spoof IP adresses?

Comment: Do you actually need the request to work? Then, IP spoofing is not an easy option, because the handshake will fail.

Comment: "to check how my graphs look when there is a lot of data" --> isolate the graph-generation functions and feed them whatever data you want? You're asking how to do black-box testing but your goal is to see the result of unit testing.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an infosec question. You can tackle this in a variety of way programatically, or run a tool locally (hping, scapy, etc) that can craft packets with whatever IP you want. Also, this is asking for a tool recommendation, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment said: IP spoofing is not an option if you want to have a working TCP connection. And you probably need this connection because otherwise the connection attempts will fail at the kernel already and your application will not get any requests.

I don't know your application setup but I see the following options:

- Some applications take a HTTP header like X-Forwarded-IP as the originating IP address, because these kind of headers are often set by reverse proxies in front of the application. If this is the case you can fake this kind of header and generate the desired HTTP requests with some scripting skills.
- If this is not the case you might setup a virtualized network with lots of different IP addresses and then do the requests from the different source IP addresses to your application (which must be on the same virtualized network setup). That's not as simple as the previous option but doable with enough knowledge on how to setup networks.